# Calling different macros inside one macro Excel VBA

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a macro that references values in a range of cells and depending on those values in that range, calls a certain macro and change the color of a cell. For example, if cell A2 has a value of 100, I want cell D2 change the color of its cell to the color red and call a certain macro once the user clicks on cell D2. So, if the user inputs 100 in cell A2, I need cell D2 to then change to the color red, indicating there needs to be more info added to the row, and once the user places their cursor on cell D2 and clicks cell D2, it takes them to a specific macro. I need this functionality for a row, (A2:A446). So, if cell A25 is 30, I need cell D25 to tunr red, and when the user clicks cell D25, it takes them to a different macro (examples are hypothetical). Please help! Here is my code below:

```
For Each c In Worksheets("JE").Range("D7:D446")
    If c.Value = "1000GP" Then
     Select.Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Call gotoref1

       ElseIf c.Value = "1000MM" Then
        Call gotoref2

        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
     ElseIf c.Value = "19FEST" Then

        Call gotoref3
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
     ElseIf c.Value = "20IEDU" Then

        Call gotoref4
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
     ElseIf c.Value = "20ONLC" Then

        Call gotoref5
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    ElseIf c.Value = "20PART" Then

        Call gotoref6
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    ElseIf c.Value = "20PRDV" Then

        Call gotoref7
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
     ElseIf c.Value = "20SPPR" Then
        Call gotoref8
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

      ElseIf c.Value = "22DANC" Then
        Call gotoref9
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    ElseIf c.Value = "22LFLC" Then
        Call gotoref10
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

      ElseIf c.Value = "22MEDA" Then
        Call gotoref11
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

     ElseIf c.Value = "530CCH" Then
        Call gotoref12
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

     ElseIf c.Value = "60PUBL" Then
        Call gotoref13
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    ElseIf c.Value = "74GA01" Then
        Call gotoref14
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    ElseIf c.Value = "74GA17" Then
        Call gotoref15
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

    ElseIf c.Value = "74GA99" Then
        Call gotoref16
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

   ElseIf c.Value = "78REDV" Then
        Call gotoref17
        Worksheets("JE").Range("F7:F446").Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

End If

Next c
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, it is somewhat unclear what you are asking for help with. Please edit your question and provide more information as to what is not working with your macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think one of your problems might be that you are using a definite cell range in your If/Elseif. Instead, you might want to use r/c reference to get from cell D7 to F7 (0,2).

What this accomplishes is for every `c` the code gives you a reference from `c` instead of passing in the entire "F" range you are trying to use.

Also, are you set on using VBA or would you be willing to use conditional formatting, and then allow the "on change of cell" in VBA to allow a `sub ()` to be called when a user changes the cell in red?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am willing to use whatever works. I was under the impression conditional formatting only works when referencing one cell, it doesn't allow you to reference a range of cells. Being that there could be upwards of 400 rows being used, i though VBA might be easier. If you wouldn't mind explaining how I can go about using the conditional formatting for this scenario.

Comment: Just to reiterate, if cell D7 (or any cell in this range) = "1000GP", I want cell F7 to change to the color red, and the user will be able to click on cell F7 which would take them to a list of possible values to choose from. If the cell D7 does not equal "1000GP" or any other values listed above cell F7 can stay as is, and the user does not need to click on cell F7 to get any more info.

Comment: The issue seems to be that, not matter what value is in the D column, when clicking on the cells in the F column, which should read the values in the D column, and depending on the value in the D column it should call a specific, separate  macro which would take the user to a list of possible values to fill in the D column. Instead it just takes the user to one macro for all values in the D COLUMN rather than the correct one.